# Getting "No services have been found." error

Tags: java, spring, cxf

I'm new to Maven, Spring and CXF and am currently trying to get a small 'Hello World' thing going where I have a REST Service available for use. I've spent a day on this and still I'm getting the dreaded "No services have been found." error when I run my project on Tomcat inside Eclipse. Below I've posted the important code from a few files. I'm hoping someone can tell me what I'm doing wrong:

web.xml:

```
<web-app>
    <display-name>Archetype Created Web Application</display-name>
    <context-param>
        <param-name>contextConfigLocation</param-name>
        <param-value>/WEB-INF/beans.xml</param-value>
    </context-param>
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <display-name>CXF Servlet</display-name>
        <servlet-class>org.apache.cxf.transport.servlet.CXFServlet</servlet-class>
    </servlet>
    <servlet-mapping>
        <servlet-name>CXFServlet</servlet-name>
        <url-pattern>/*</url-pattern>
    </servlet-mapping>
</web-app>
```

beans.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans
    xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws"
    xmlns:jaxrs="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs" xsi:schemaLocation="  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans  http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans.xsd  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxrs  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxrs.xsd  http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws  http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd">
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
    <import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
    <bean id="bookserviceclass" class="org.ahmad.restTest1.restServices.BookService" />
    <jaxrs:server id="bookservice" address="/">
        <jaxrs:serviceBeans>
            <ref bean="bookserviceclass" />
        </jaxrs:serviceBeans>
    </jaxrs:server>
</beans>
```

BookService.java:

```
package org.ahmad.restTest1.restServices;

import org.ahmad.restTest1.vo.BookVO;
import javax.ws.rs.*;
import javax.ws.rs.core.MediaType;
import javax.ws.rs.core.Response;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.net.URLDecoder;
import java.util.HashMap;

@Path("/")
public class BookService {

 private static HashMap < BookVO, BookVO > hashMap;

 @GET
 @Path("/randomMsg/{name}")
 @Produces({
  MediaType.APPLICATION_JSON
 })
 public Response getSomeMessage(@PathParam("name") String name) {

  return Response.ok(name + "123").build();
 }
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have some configuration errors.

Include spring listener in `web.xml`

```
<listener>
    <listener-class>org.springframework.web.context.ContextLoaderListener</listener-class>
</listener>
```

Remove this lines in `beans.xml` . They are not needed in latest versions of CXF

```
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-extension-soap.xml" />
<import resource="classpath:META-INF/cxf/cxf-servlet.xml" />
```

After this, the server will be available executing

```
http://localhost:8080/yourdeploydir/randomMsg/hello
```